# docker-compose doesn't start mysql:8 correctly

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, amazon-ami

I'm running docker on AWS AMI and getting following error while I want to run mysql:8 container using `docker-compose`. I have created the data volume this container needs.

Snip of my docker-compose file is

```
version: '3.7'

services:
   mysql:
     image: mysql:8
     command: bash -c "rm /etc/localtime && ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/New_York /etc/localtime && mysqld --user=root --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password"
     volumes:
       - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
       - ./:/home
     ports:
      - "3306:3306"
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example

...
mysql-data:
      external:
        name: data-volume
```

and I get following error, I'm not sure what data directory is the error referring to

```
mysql_1                | 2019-09-20T03:13:24.151141Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010139] [Server] Changed limits: max_open_files: 1024 (requested 8161)
mysql_1                | 2019-09-20T03:13:24.151148Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010142] [Server] Changed limits: table_open_cache: 431 (requested 4000)
mysql_1                | 2019-09-20T03:13:24.433348Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011070] [Server] 'Disabling symbolic links using --skip-symbolic-links (or equivalent) is the default. Consider not using this option as it' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
mysql_1                | 2019-09-20T03:13:24.433434Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.17) starting as process 1
mysql_1                | 2019-09-20T03:13:24.443292Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-011011] [Server] Failed to find valid data directory.
mysql_1                | 2019-09-20T03:13:24.443383Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
mysql_1                | 2019-09-20T03:13:24.445787Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
mysql_1                | 2019-09-20T03:13:24.446197Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.17)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

Comment: try to add `mysqld --user=root --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password --ignore-db-dir=lost+found`

Comment: https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/69

Comment: Also a few suggestions, set time zone from ENV, set user from ENV, remove named volume try with bind volume, also you do not need to bind `home`

Comment: was your mysql-data properly defined beforehand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `docker-compose.yml` overrides the `CMD` defined in the official MySql [Dockerfile](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-docker/blob/main/mysql-server/8.0/Dockerfile)
(i.e `["mysqld]"`). The default entrypoint ([docker-entrypoint.sh](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/master/8.0/docker-entrypoint.sh))
does not initialize the container if the command doesn't start with `mysqld`(`mysqld` should be the first argument of the entrypoint script). As a consequence the data directory doesn't get created, hence the error. The data directory is the directory where the database files are created.

To run with the custom `command` configured in the compose file you should initialize the `mysql-data` volume before starting the container:

```
docker run --rm \
  --name init-mysql \
  -v mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql \
  -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD="example" \
  mysql:8
```

Then stop the container

```
docker stop init-mysql
```

Start again the container using `docker-compose`.

In alternative you could write a custom entrypoint. Hope it helps